# How to open 2 link or more pages when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I open 2 or more pages when a button is clicked in HTML and JavaScript?

html

```
<td style="background-color:#EE9933;">
    <input type="button" id="logtkt" value="Item Logs tkt" class="button" 
      style="Color:blue;width:170px;position: relative;Top: 1px;Left: 1px" 
      onclick="logtkt()"/>
</td>
```

js

```
function tktNum() {
  var str = document.getElementById('tktTree').value;
  var t;
  var res = str.substr(1, 10);
  if (str.substr(0, 1) == 0) {
    t = res;
  } else {
    t = str;
  }
  tktTree.value = t;
}


function logtkt() {
  var t = document.getElementById('tktTree').value;
  parent.open("http://-----=" + t + "");
}
```

Comment: you mean open two other tabs with other url ?

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. They're two different languages and should not be confused.

Answer (score 2):

```
    clickMe.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open('https://bbc.co.uk', '_blank');
        window.open('https://news.sky.com', '_blank');
    });
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: thanks , but I want to keep the variable in each link or if you can help me modify the text above

Comment: using string template literals

Comment: ````  clickMe.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(`https://bbc.co.uk/${pageno}`, '_blank');
        window.open('https://news.sky.com', '_blank');
    }); `

Comment: i use this but it open one link only No two

Comment: can you attach a snippet of your code or screen shot?